# Error React native - React Navigation

Tags: android, react-native

tengo este problema al querer instalar React Navigation en Windows con npm
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego cuando importo el componente

```
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigator'
```

al Emular en android me bota el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: como creaste tu proyecto, con  **react-native-cli** o create-react-native-app   version de react que tienes instalado en tus dependencias ?.

Comment: Al instalar la libreria utilizaste `react-navigation` y al importarla usaste `react-navigator`. Hay que analizar un poco mas.

Answer (score 3):

El problema es sencillo de componer.

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
```

Cambia la parte donde tipeas react-navigator a react-navigation y debe funcionar.
Para javascript se tiene que tener mucho cuidado ya que es case-sensitive y en este caso estas haciendo incorrecta la importación

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas tener el archivo `package.json`. Para crearlo puedes usar el siguiente comando:

```
$ npm init
```

Al parecer en windows el paquete no se instala a menos que tengas este archivo.